# qml component connects with signal

Tags: c++, qml

I have a component/delegate declared in qml and  I would like to connect one o its actions to a signal in another qml or C++ class. So, the Component looks like this:

```
Component
{
     id: mainButtonDelegate
     Button {
        id: buttonOperation
        text: qsTr(buttonText)         
        buttonEnabled: false
        onIsEnableChanged:
        {
            buttonEnabled = cppRegisteredClass.isButtonEnabled(text)
        }
    }  
}
```

Can I create connection for the component (so for every button), like the following expressed in Qt?
    `connect(loginForm, SIGNAL(loginChanged()), this, SLOT(onIsEnableChanged()))`

My model is a ListModel expressed in a qml file.

**Edit**

If this is not the correct approach could somebody suggest me another way to do sth like this?

Comment: You can connect an item instance, not `Component`. `Component` is just a prototype.  Look at [Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) type.  More info could be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html)

Comment: Then how I can connect each item with the desired signal/slot? In the model? Then I have to write the onIsEnableChanged:{... many times

Comment: In your example, you only need to write it once, as it is in the delegate and will be automatically connected like this for each instance of the `mainButtonDelegate` - what else do you want?

Comment: derM, thank you very much for the help, but I have tested what you suggest and it does not work. Have you done such a test on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-connections.html)-object.

You expression would be translated to:

```
Connections {
    target: loginForm
    onLoginChanged: whatIsThis.onIsEnabledChanged()
}
```

Alternatively you can use the JS connect syntax:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals

You expression would translate to:

```
loginForm.loginChanged.connect(this.onIsEnabledChanged)
```

Comment: What do you think it should entered in 'whatIsThis' ? The id of the button? Because I add the id and qml says that there is not function onIsEnabledChanged. I have also added: signal isEnableChanged() in the Button

Comment: In your `expression` you connect to a slot called `onIsEnabledChagend` of an object that is referenced by `this`. In the `Connections`-object you can't use `this` as that would be the `Connections`-object. Instead you need to use the id of what is `this` in your example.

Comment: As I have mentioned before, if I set the id of the button there, I get that there is no such function

Answer (score 0):

I am posting how I have done what I wanted, just if anyone else need this.
I have added a function in the model and used set property.

```
function action()
{
    for(var i= 0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        if(backend.disable())
        {
            setProperty(i, "enable", false)
            setProperty(i, "opac", 0.3)
        }
        else
        {
            setProperty(i, "enable", true)
            setProperty(i, "opac", 1)
        }
    }
}
```

In the component (inside an Item parent), I have added:

```
            LoginForm{
            id: loginForm
            onLoginIdentityChanged: {
                mymodel.action()
            }
```